# How to obtain coordinate of d3 label text?

Tags: d3.js

I need the coordinates of each Label in : http://www.bigcamerabutton.com/bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/

How can I obtain them? I want to place my image icon next to each label, but I cannot get the correct x and y coords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.getBBox()` on a node to get the position and size of its bounding box.

If you wanted a bounding box for each label in that example, you could do the following:

```
var labelBBoxes = d3.selectAll('text')[0].map(function(d) {
  return {
    element: d,
    bbox: d.getBBox()
  }
});
```

This takes the array of all text elements, and maps each element to an object containing the element and its bounding box.

Each bounding box has the same properties as a `<rect>` element (in fact it is a rect element): `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

To get you started you might try something like this:

```
// loop through the bbox array you made
labelBBoxes.forEach(function(d) {
  // append an image to the element's parent `<g>`
  d3.select(d.element.parentNode).append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'path/to/your/image.png')
    .attr('width', widthOfYourImage)
    .attr('height', heightOfYourImage)
    .attr('x', d.bbox.x)
    .attr('y', d.bbox.y);
});
```

From there you'll probably want to tweak the position and rotation and all, but it's a start.